# Prove that $1_{A \Delta B} = 1_A + 1_B - 2\cdot 1_{A \cap B}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A, B \subset X$. If $A \Delta B= (A-B) \cup (B-A)$, then

$$1_{A \Delta B} = 1_A + 1_B - 2\cdot 1_{A \cap B}$$

I got this identity from this site some time ago. I can't find the link to see if there was a proof also there or not, and I'm curious to see how would one go about proving this result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to math.se. It helps potential answerers if you can provide some context for your question, like what progress you've made toward proving it yourself.

Comment: Where does $C$ come from?

Comment: Also, should the union in the definition be $(A - B) \cup (B - A)$?

Comment: Okay. I tried writing the characteristic functions explicitly and checked to see where element of the sets $B$ and $A$ would go, and then did some rough checks to see if both sides are the same. Didn't make much progress.

Comment: There's a typo in the question. I'll fix it. There is no $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would go about proving this result the same way one would go about proving any result. By verifying the definitions.

Recall that two functions with the same domain are equal, if and only if they have the same value for each element of the domain. So all you need to check is that for every $x\in X$ it holds that $1_{A\triangle B}(x) = 1_A(x)+1_B(x)-1_{A\cap B}(x)$.

We have two cases, either $x\in A\triangle B$, or $x\notin A\triangle B$.

1. $x\in A\triangle B$, then $1_{A\triangle B}(x)=1$; on the other hand this means that either $x\in A-B$ or $x\in B-A$.

   - If $x\in A-B$ then $1_A(x)=1$, but $1_B(x)=0$, and so must $1_{A\cap B}(x)$. Therefore $1=1+0-0=1$.
   - If $x\in B-A$ ...
2. $x\notin A\triangle B$, then ...

And you should fill in the rest yourself.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks. I'll get to work on it now. I tried approaching this the same way you did, initially, just got confused by the notation a little.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You have to prove

- $1_{A\cap B}=1_A1_B$
- $1_{A\cup B}=1_A+1_B-1_{A\cap B}$
- $1_{A^c}=1-1_A$

and notice that

$$A-B=A\cap B^c$$